# Need help programming chamberlain garage door opener replacement KLIK3U-BK

Tags: garage-door-opener

I just moved into this rental house in November and am trying to get a second garage door opener to work.

There's an existing working KLIK3U-BK model, so I ordered a second one of those. But none of the programming instructions I've tried work for me:

- The opener itself says "press the learn button, then press & hold the remote button" until the learn button blinks.
- Internet search shows "press the learn button, then press & hold the remote button for 3 seconds" then try the remote.
- A previous search said "press the learn button" then try the remote button 4 or 6 or 8 times and it will start to work depending on the model on one of those presses.

None of this works at all. Should I:

- wipe the programming of all remotes from the opener first? (This will be bad if I can't get the existing one working again).
- Try a different model of the remote like the 953EV?

Any other ideas? Having one remote for 2 cars is cramping our style a bit ...

Comment: Call Chamberlain / Liftmaster customer support.  They are amazing.  They help new homeowner reprogram codes and add/drop transmitters all the time.  They won't ask if your in or out of warranty they will just help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was on hold for quite a while, but Liftmaster customer support answered my question quickly. For the KLIK3U-BK and the model of the openers we have installed (purple Learn button), the key was that there's a hidden button on the remote that you expose by sliding down a panel in front below the external buttons. Calling this the 'remote programming button':

Then:

- Press and hold the remote programming button until the light on the remote comes on
- Press the Learn button ... its little light will come on
- Press the button on the remote that you want to program to activate this opener 3 times. The learn button's light goes out

That's it. Just test the opener button you programmed and it should work. Put the cover back in place and you're done!

Answer (score 2):

I had same issue, trying to program to a Liftmaster. Here's what worked for me:

- Liftmaster: Press learn button.
- Klik3U: Press programming button unitl LED solid BLue.
- Press-release desired button on klik3u until Lifmaster lights blink.
- Press Klik3U programming button to turn off programming mode.
  Done.

I had to press the target button 8 times...hope that helps.